# How can I import a global-scope file into my react native project

Tags: react-native, azure-application-insights

I need to use a 3rd party file in my react-native application that assumes it has a global context. It has no es6 or node-style exports at all. Is there any way to inject this 3rd party file into my react-native project?

Sample of the content of the 3rd party file:

```
var Module;
(function (Module) {
    var SubModule;
    (function (SubModule) {
        "use strict";
    })(SubModule = Module.SubModule || (Module.SubModule = {}));
})(Module || (Module = {}));
...
```

As we can see, things seem to be organized into a module system to prevent too much global scope pollution. There is no `export` or `module.exports` to work with though.

------- edit ----------

Per suggestion, I tried the `import 'file';` syntax with a file, and it "compiles" but doesn't put the vars in global scope.

in a test.js file:

```
/* eslint-disable */
var mytest = {
    test: () => console.log("test run success");
};
console.log("test file evaluated");
```

then in my main App.js file

```
import './test';
...
/* global mytest */
mytest.test();
```

The "test file evaluated" message is logged out, but the application throws a "ReferenceError: mytest is not defined" on the `mytest.test();` line.

Comment: Could you try import ```"path-to-js-file";```? This should import whole file into wherever you want, most probably you want to do this in your index.js file.

Comment: Added an edit to show the results of this. In short it works, but doesn't accomplish what I need.